# Power BI - counting number of times a value occurs across multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to count number of times a value is found in a row. For instance, if cell values are Pass and Fail for various columns as below, I want to be able to calculate the Count Pass and Count Fail column.

| Activity | Initiation | Methodology | Regulations | Innovation | Overall | Count Pass | Count Fail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pass | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Pass | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | Fail | Fail | Pass | Pass | Fail | 2 | 3 |

I tried using `PassCount = COUNTAX ('Result', ALL('Result') = "PASS")` but got error `"The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."` I am pretty sure that is not the right way to do, since I am new to Power BI I have been trying a lot of these, but none seems to work.

Thank you in advance for any help of suggestions.

Comment: How many columns are there to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An M solution would be add column, custom column, with

```
 = List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.ToList(_), each if _="Pass" then 1 else 0))
```

or

```
 = List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.ToList(_), each if _="Fail" then 1 else 0))
```

Comment: Thank you @horseyride, this is exactly what I was looking for as it also solves the issue if there are large number of columns to be checked. You're a legend mate. :)

Comment: Nice one. Tried this myself and came to something similar using `List.Count(List.Select(Record.ToList(_), each _="Pass"))` and `List.Count(List.Select(Record.ToList(_), each _="Fail"))`

Comment: I suppose even `List.Count(List.FindText(Record.ToList(_), "Pass"))` and `List.Count(List.FindText(Record.ToList(_), "Fail"))` will work

Answer (score 0):

This you can achieve in Power Query

Do following steps:

1. Create Pass custom column with `if [parameter] = "Pass" then 1 else 0` for each parameter and add all those columns using Addition
2. Create Fail custom column with `if [parameter] = "Fail" then 1 else 0` for each parameter and add all those columns using Addition
3. Remove all custom columns except resulted Pass and Fail columns

Here is the M code

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data27jul23.xlsx"), null, true),
    Result_Sheet = Source{[Item="Result",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Result_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Activity", Int64.Type}, {"Initiation", type text}, {"Methodology", type text}, {"Regulations", type text}, {"Innovation", type text}, {"Overall", type text}, {"Count Pass", Int64.Type}, {"Count Fail", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Count Pass", "Count Fail"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Initiation_Pass", each if [Initiation] = "Pass" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Methodology_Pass", each if [Methodology] = "Pass" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Regulations_Pass", each if [[Regulations]] = "Pass" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Innovation_Pass", each if [Innovation] = "Pass" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Overall_Pass", each if [Overall] = "Pass" then 1 else 0),
    #"Inserted Sum" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Count Pass", each List.Sum({[Initiation_Pass], [Methodology_Pass], [Regulations_Pass], [Innovation_Pass], [Overall_Pass]}), type number),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Sum", "Initiation_Fail", each if [Initiation] = "Fail" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom5", "Methodology_Fail", each if [Methodology] = "Fail" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom6", "Regulations_Fail", each if [Regulations] = "Fail" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom7", "Innovation_Fail", each if [Innovation] = "Fail" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom9" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom8", "Overall_Fail", each if [Overall] = "Fail" then 1 else 0),
    #"Inserted Sum1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom9", "Count Fail", each List.Sum({[Initiation_Fail], [Methodology_Fail], [Regulations_Fail], [Innovation_Fail], [Overall_Fail]}), type number),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Sum1",{"Initiation_Pass", "Methodology_Pass", "Regulations_Pass", "Innovation_Pass", "Overall_Pass", "Initiation_Fail", "Methodology_Fail", "Regulations_Fail", "Innovation_Fail", "Overall_Fail"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Because of limition in column width adjustment in Power Query table, entire image could not be captured

Comment: Record.ToList(_) would return the value from all the columns in a single list that you could use. I provided an example as a different answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have small amount (10+/-) of column to count on, you can create 2 new column as below-

```
count_pass = 
    if(your_table_name[Initiation] = "Pass",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Methodology] = "Pass",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Regulations] = "Pass",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Innovation] = "Pass",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Overall] = "Pass",1,0)
```

```
count_fail = 
    if(your_table_name[Initiation] = "Fail",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Methodology] = "Fail",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Regulations] = "Fail",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Innovation] = "Fail",1,0)
    + if(your_table_name[Overall] = "Fail",1,0)
```

You can add as many column as you wants to the list, but this will be unmanageable when you have more columns. Here is the sample output-

[image]

Comment: thank you mkrabbani, your solution also resolves my issue but also check out the solution by @horseyride as it is more dynamic if we have large number of columns to be checked. thanks again for your help